# If form response cell is = 200 then SUM in the next cell

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

[image]

```
    =IF('Form Responses 4'!B2:B115,"Jimmy", IF('Form Responses 4'!H2:H115=250))
```

So I'm trying to make it work to if in the Form Responses 4 sheet from `H2` to `H115` the number in those cells is `=` to `250` then `SUM` the numbers submitted from `G2` to `G115`

thanks in advance

Comment: If Google why the excel tag a not a Google sheets tag?

Answer (score 0):

```
=SUMIFS('Form Responses 4'!G2:G115,'Form Responses 4'!B2:B115="Jimmy",'Form Responses 4'!H2:H115=250)
```

Comment: argument invalid

Comment: Corrected. If not working, share a copy of your sheet.

Comment: i have gave up on using that method and right now im trying to do another solution, this method "=SUMIF('Form Responses 4'!B2:B121,"Jimmy", 'Form Responses 4'!H2:H121*'Form Responses 4'!G2:G121)" is not working

Comment: So do you still want to ask for a solution or want to try yourself? You are not answer to our questions nor providing additional information.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=SUM(FILTER('Form Responses 4'!G2:G115; 1*'Form Responses 4'!H2:H115=250))
```

Comment: argument invalid

Comment: @ZateFeto updated... can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: i have gave up on using that method and right now im trying to do another solution, this method "=SUMIF('Form Responses 4'!B2:B121,"Jimmy", 'Form Responses 4'!H2:H121*'Form Responses 4'!G2:G121)" is not working